# How do you modify Jenkins configuration from a shared-library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins allows us to grab a Singelton of the running instance with jenkins.[get()](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html#get--). I'm trying to build a class in my shared-library that CRUD's the cloud providers. My code looks like this.

```
@NonCPS
def create(){
  Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
  // logic to create cloud
  jenkins.clouds.add(tmpCloud)
  jenkins.save()
}

@NonCPS
def delete(){
  Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
  def newlist = jenkins.clouds.findAll{ it.getDisplayName() != cloud }
  if(newlist){
     jenkins.clouds.clear()
  }
  for ( int i = 0; i < newlist.size; i++ ) {
    jenkins.clouds.add(newlist[i])
  }
  jenkins.save()
}
```

If I run just the create() function the code works as expected, same if I run just the delete(), but if I run both in the same job like this.

```
cloud.create()
cloud.delete()
```

Then only the create will work, the delete wont error but it wont do anything either. Is it possible to reinitialize a singleton? I feel like that is what I need to do. I have tried saving the jenkins instance as a field of my class, but that leads to a hudson serializable error. I dont see a way to pass the jenkins singleton around because of CPS issues.

Comment: The question title asks about modifying a Jenkins configuration from a shared library, but the question asks about retrieving Jenkins instance status via Groovy and Jenkins library intrinsics. Which are you looking for here?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I would like to create and delete a "cloud" in one job run. I already know how to retrieve the jenkins singelton, but in order to create and delete the configuration we will need to bypass some of the limitations jenkins has put on Groovy (CPS) by knowing some of them library intrinsics.